# AWS(EC2) response request timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to connect AWS(EC2) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Base

After I create the EC2, I connect it.

but EC2 response request timeout message. (I use the chrome to access AWS EC2)

+) I complete the port open.

- HTTP 80 / Anywhere (Problem)
- Custom TCP Rule 7579 / Anywhere (Problem)
- RDP 443 / Anywhere (not problem to Access)

What should I do if I use EC2?

Thank you!!

Comment: RDP port is not 443, should be 3389

Comment: Open HTTPS 443 / Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0), I believe that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical things to check when trying to connect to an EC2 instance:

**Security Groups**

Check that at least one of the Security Groups associated with the instance has port 22 (SSH) or port 3389 (RDP) open to your source IP range (eg a specific IP address 54.87.23.11/32, or the whole world 0.0.0.0/0 -- but the latter is very poor security practice). Security Groups are stateful, so you only need to open **Inbound** access and the return path will automatically work.

**Public IP Address**

Confirm that you are using a Public IP address associated with the instance. This can either be assigned at instance launch (which will allocate a random IP address from a pool) or can be assigned as an Elastic IP Address (which is a static IP address that you can assign assign to any instance and you keep it until you release it back to AWS).

**Public Subnet / Routing**

Confirm that your instance is in a "Public" VPC Subnet. This means that the Route Table associated with the Subnet has a route through an Internet Gateway.

**AMI Operating System**

I've seen situations where people try to SSH to a Windows instance, or RDP to a Linux instance, so also check that you launched the correct AMI for your expected operating system.